# Can two different typeclasses have the same method names?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Suppose I have

```
class Foo a where
    (++=) :: a -> a -> a
    cool  :: (a -> b -> b) -> a -> b
```

and want to make

```
class Bar a where
    (++=) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
    magic :: a -> b
```

which has an overlapping method name, `(++=)`. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: In OOP, same-name methods are allowed because the type of the `this` object can disambiguate among them. In Haskell, there's no `this` around: methods for `Foo a` do not implicitly take an `a` argument. Even if they did, type inference would become quite complicated, since you need to compute the type of `this` _before_ you can know the type of the method. In most OOP languages, there's no or little type inference w.r.t. functional languages, so this is not a problem there.

Comment: Also, these are functions not methods, to be precise.

Comment: @Erik Alik: Actually, even though it's very different from the OO concept, [the word 'method' is technically correct](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has a subtle "no but yes" kind of answer, which requires going into three concepts:

1. Qualified names vs. unqualified names
2. Modules and imports
3. Aliasing

Point 1: every definition in Haskell has both a short, unqualified name like `map`, and a long, qualified name like `Data.List.map`.

Point 2: when you import a module into another, you can do either a qualified or an unqualified import.  When you use unqualified import, the foreign module's names that you bring in will be aliased under their short names.  When you do a qualified import, they will only be available under a modified name:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

Now in the module where this appeared, the `Data.Map.map` function is visible under the alias `Data.map`.

Third point: this means that every Haskell definition has a fully qualified name determined by its short name and the module where it's defined, but also unqualified or partially qualified aliases in each module where it is imported.

Now, your question has two answers:

1. Two different classes **cannot** have methods that share the same *fully qualified* name.  So if you define your `Foo` and `Bar` classes in the same module, that will fail.
2. Two different classes **can** have methods that share the same *unqualified name*, as long as their fully qualified names are different—i.e., they're defined in different modules.  To use both within one client module, however, you will need at least one qualified import so the aliases from the import don't clash.

Comment: In your example you mean `Map.map`, or `import qualified Data.Map as Data`,  right?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot, at least within the same module. You *can* declare `class Foo` and `class Bar` in two different modules and import each of them into the same file, but you'll still have to `qualify` at least one of those imports to avoid conflicts.

Comment: So it's "yes, you can, if ..." not "no you cannotl :)

Comment: @ErikAllik They literally can't have the same names. Qualifying causes them to have different names.

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles without any errors:

Main.hs:

```
module Main where

import qualified Foo
import Bar

instance Foo.Foo Char where
    c1 ++= c2 = c1

instance Bar Char where
    f ++= c = f c

main = do
    putStrLn $ [ 'a' Foo.++= 'b' ]
```

Foo.hs:

```
module Foo where

class Foo a where
    (++=) :: a -> a -> a
```

Bar.hs:

```
module Bar where

class Bar a where
    (++=) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

So, in other words, we don't need to reference `++=` using its fully qualified name inside the instance declaration, but when used inside `main`, we need to specify which `++=` we're talking about. In the instance declaration, we've already defined the scope for `++=`, while `main` wouldn't know which one was being referred to, if we used unqualified imports. Therefore, if all we wanted to do was to define class instances, then we wouldn't need the qualified import.